# A value of type 'List<Data>?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Data>'

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I'm trying to fetch data in Flutter from test API using this tutorial - https://flutterforyou.com/how-to-fetch-data-from-api-and-show-in-flutter-listview/

When I copy the code VS Code throws this error, and I do not understand, what I need to do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYXNO.png)

Thank for your responses, and sorry in advance for dummy question, code example

```
    Future <List<Data>> fetchData() async {
  
  final response =
      await http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return jsonResponse.map((data) => Data.fromJson(data)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Unexpected error occured!');
  }
}

class Data {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;

  Data({required this.userId, required this.id, required this.title});

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      userId: json['userId'],
      id: json['id'],
      title: json['title'],
    );
  }
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  late Future <List<Data>> futureData;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureData = fetchData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter API and ListView Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter ListView'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder <List<Data>>(
            future: futureData,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                List<Data> data = snapshot.data;
                return 
                ListView.builder(
                itemCount: data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Container(
                    height: 75,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Center(child: Text(data[index].title),
                  ),);
                }
              );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("${snapshot.error}");
              }
              // By default show a loading spinner.
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Change this : List<Data>? data = snapshot.data;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of List? means that this list can be null.

But List means that this list can not be null, but could be empty as [];

Solutions:
**Make List be List?**
This will make your List nullable, and you will have to refactor your code anywhere where it is used to perform null checks.
For this, edit your builder method line to this:

```
List<Data>? data = snapshot.data;
```

I'd not recommend this though, because you shall have to perform manual nullity checks in your code, which is not that beautiful

**Check for nullity of List?**
I'd recommend using this, you have to change your builder method to this for null checking..

```
List<Data> data = snapshot.data ?? <Data>[];
```

What this code means is it will try `snapshot.data`, if it returns null, it will assign `<Data>[]` to the data array. Making it an empty array.

This is more easy to deal with(based on my views) than a nullable array!

Comment: Thank you, it helped!

But I have one more question

I tried tutorial to get an access to API on this link - http://filehost.feelsoftware.com/jsonplaceholder/cars-api.php

I changed my code to this

class Data {
  ...
  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Data(
      number: json['cars']['number'],
      date: json['cars']['date'],
      state: json['cars']['state'],
    );
  }
}

it throws _internallinkhashmap<string, dynamic> is not a subtype of List<dynamic>

Comment: if you have telegram, ping me with https://t.me/lightema, I will be able to help you there more

Answer (score 4):

This error can be solved by updating your code like this,

```
List<Data> data = snapshot.data ?? <Data>[];
```

or like this,

```
List<Data> data = snapshot.data!;
```

Answer (score 3):

`snapshot.data` could be null, you already know it is not null because of this line

```
if (snapshot.hasData)
```

But dart doesn't know that yet... To let it know, you can use the `!` operator after data

```
List<Data> data = snapshot.data!;
```

Comment: since it might return null, wont null be data in snapshot.hasData?

Comment: @emanuelsanga Sorry, not sure I understand your question, `snapshot.hasData` will only be true if `snapshot.data` is **not null**, even if the future is completed.

Comment: I get this, what am asking is, will flutter not treat null as data, given that the function passed can be nullable?

Comment: no, as you can see in the [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html) data will **never** be null as long as `snapshot.hasData` is true, even if the future is completed and the function is nullable

Comment: thanks for that @hmoss, I missed something there